# Way to query all distinct edges in AQL

Tags: arangodb

Previously,I can use the following to get all unique edges from a vertex

```
FOR v,c
IN 1..3
ANY "EntityA/A"
EDGES
OPTIONS {uniqueEdges:global,bfs: true}
RETURN c
```

Since 3.3.5, there is undocumentated change in AQL traversal that `uniqueEdges:global` is no longer supported. Does this mean that there is no way to query distinct edges in AQL?

One solution is to use DISTINCT, but to my understanding, this is a filter function after the traversal has been done, thus, do not help with the performance.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed the option `uniqueEdges:global` is not supported in recent 3.2 and 3.3 versions and the support of it is not planned for next releases. For now using `RETURN DISTINCT` is a working approach.

This [pull request](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/5471) removes the unsupported option from the documentation.

Comment: But that is in AQL, if I want the edges to be disticnt in traversal object (Foxx), then how can I do it?